# Error :- WSE594: InitializeSecurityContext call failed with the following error message: The network path was not found

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, kerberos, wse

good 
I'm trying to authenticate to web services with kerberos, but when I try to invoke the web service gives me the following error:

Error :- WSE594: InitializeSecurityContext call failed with the following error message: The network path was not found

Can anyone tell me what is?

Comment: Why are you using WSE for _anything_? It's very obsolete and is unsupported. As a result, there are very few people who know anything about it.

Comment: yes, I know I should use wcf but do not know how, I am new at this and I can not use the wcf. Can you give me any tips?

Comment: Yes, I can give you a tip. WSE is obsolete and not supported by Microsoft. Do not use it. Take a day and begin learning WCF. See [tag:wcf] and even [this](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/). It's from the point of view of consuming a service, but creates one as an example.

Comment: And for example, do not create any web service, only have access to the wsdl, and I do not know if it is or not created in WCF. When the mind for visual studio and then invoke, can when I'm invoking introduce a kerberos ticket in the request header?

Comment: It doesn't need to be created in WCF. Just start with "Add Service Reference" and go from there.

Comment: but this I know ... 
add to "Add Service Reference", then I do not know is how to invoke the service put a kerberos ticket in order? 

Just found examples using WSE

Comment: Ignore WSE. Any WSE examples you find are ancient. Do not use them.

Comment: can get me a recent example of wcf who can show me? It's just that I do not find ...

Comment: Stop looking for examples. Start learning WCF. "Looking for examples" is how you found WSE. That should have taught you not to do that any more.